# Relative path call not functioning

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a script for a class and am trying to call a function in another folder into the script, I've done this exactly the way I have it written for many other scripts, though it was in a different respository/workspace.
Here's the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'Mathematical Functions')
print(sys.path)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as mt
from FourthOrRungeKut import RungeKutta as RK4
```

The import call of the FourthOrRungeKut script returns error "Import "FourthOrRungeKut" could not be resolved.

For reference, here's an image of my directory:

[image]

The interpreter is treating the correct file as the root, it appears the line `sys.path.insert(0, 'Mathematical Functions')`
Is not appending the folder so the interpreter can locate the FourthOrRungeKut script.

For reference, here is the repository path (and the path that `os.getcwd()` returns):

C:\Users\falco\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Num-Methods-Final-Project.

This exact setup works perfectly in another repository I have made.

Comment: Before the problematic import print the result of "os.getcwd()" to know the current working directory (relative paths are based on it).

Comment: Just tried it, the interpreter is in the correct folder @Michael Butscher

Comment: Which file contains the code in the first snippet? How do you run the code? Are you running it from the command line or in VS Code?

Comment: The Lab Scripts File @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @TannerBurton `Lab Scripts` looks like a folder, not a file.

Comment: Whoops, my bad, mixed up file and folder there, its in Burton_T_lab_08_1109, the yellow highlighted file @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Add `print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])` to your script. What does it print out?

Comment: And how do you run the code? Are you running it from the command line or in VS Code?

Comment: That command is bringing an error, maybe i'm inputting the wrong path, I'm inputting "C:\Users\falco\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Num-Methods-Final-Project." in place of "PYTHONPATH". Im running it through vscode

Comment: Add the command exactly as I typed it in my comment above. Don't replace anything.

Comment: And will you answer my other questions, please?

Comment: That brings an error too, I'm running the code through vscode using its "run code and debug" feature (pressing f5)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: And how do you run the code? Are you running it from the command line or in VS Code?

Comment: Exception has occurred: KeyError
'PYTHONPATH'

Comment: Ok, that just means `PYTHONPATH` isn't set. How do you run the code? Are you running it from the command line or in VS Code?

Comment: I'm running it in vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `FourthOrRungeKut` to extra path then it won't throw the error:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "./Mathmetical Functions"
]
```

[image]

Comment: This did it, I realized that the rungekutta file was inside a hidden pychache folder, after moving that out and implementing this, it finally works as intended.

Comment: @TannerBurton. Glad to know my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is about pathing. `FourthOrRungeKut.py` is in a folder named `Mathematical Functions`. When you do `from FourthOrRungeKut import RungeKutta as RK4` it looks for `FourthOrRungeKut.py` in the root of your project.

To fix the problem, you first need to rename `Mathematical Functions` so that it is a valid module name in python. This means that you cannot use spaces in the folder. If you rename the folder to `math`, then you can do

```
from math.FourthOrRungeKut import RungeKutta as RK4
```

In general, treat file and folder names the as if they are variable names: don't use spaces or special characters.

Comment: So the ```sys.path.insert(0, 'Mathematical Functions')``` line is meant to resolve the pathing issue, appending the mathematical functions folder so the interpreter can find the FourthOrRungeKut Script. I tried your suggestion and it returns the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Math"

Comment: @TannerBurton The interpreter uses an environment variable named `PYTHONPATH` to search for python modules. Modifying `sys.path` doesn't do what you think it does as this modifies the `PATH` environment variable. As for the error, double check the case. Do the file name and code match?

Comment: I see, that might explain why it works in one repository and not in another. I checked again to make sure the names match and they do, I also tried a few other folder names. It appears unable to find the folder. I also actually got it to start working by deleting and recreating the folders. Now it works, but vscode says it shouldn't it's very odd behavior. @Code-Apprentice